# Command line (or even programmatically) retrieving portions of an image

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I have an app that does some processing on screen shots on the server (linux) and specifically I want to split the image into 4 or 6 parts. It's possible that the image has 4 images (one in each quadrant). So is there a way to split this using a command line tool? Six in some other cases. Let's assume I will know how many to cut the images into.

So is there a command line utility to do this? Irrespective of the size of the image there has to be linux utilities to do this. I am drawing a blank.

Comment: The http://www.imagemagick.org/ tool `convert` probably has an easy way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `imagemagick` you can split an image in tiles, such as:

```
convert -crop <width>%x<height>%@ original_file.png  tile_%d.png
```

with `<width>%` and `<height>%` given in percentage of the dimension.

So for the four tiles case you can split the image as:

```
convert -crop 50%x50%@ original_file.png  tile_%d.png
```

and for the six tiles:

```
convert -crop 50%x33%@ original_file.png  tile_%d.png
```

(or `33%x50%@` if there are three horizontally)